# Unknown type name C

Tags: c

I know that things have to be defined before they are used, but I am getting an "unknown type name error."

This is my `Node` definition:

```
struct Node  {
    position* p;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
};
```

This is my declaration (on line 96):

```
Node* hashtable[HashArraySize];
```

I get this error message:

```
P1.c:96:1: error: unknown type name ‘Node’
 Node* hashtable[HashArraySize];
```

Comment: write `typedef struct Node Node;`

Comment: or `struct Node* hashtable[HashArraySize];`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike C++ which treats `struct` tags as new type names, C requires an explicit typedef if you wish to use `Node` without `struct`:

```
typedef struct Node Node;
```

Alternatively, you could use `struct Node` in your declaration:

```
struct Node* hashtable[HashArraySize];
```

Comment: which is cleaner/better in your opinion?

Comment: @A.Allen If there are multiple functions that take `struct Node`, then `typedef` is cleaner. If there's only one or two places where `Node` needs to be used, `struct Node` is slightly cleaner. The important thing is to decide on one approach, and do it consistently for all your `struct`s.

Comment: @A.Allen Personally I despise `typedef`s. I like to know what I'm working with. Steam comes out of my ears when I have to search back through nested `.h` files to find out what something is (not bad in an IDE, terrible in Vi (grep helps)). And my personal favorite, when 2 `.h` files from different places have `typedef`ed two different types to the same name. IMO, only time to use `typedefs` is if you have a type name that's really "long" or if your code will run on several different platforms where the primitive types for each may be/are different. Experienced vets please tell me why Im wrong

Answer (score 6):

Change `Node* hashtable[HashArraySize];` to `struct Node* hashtable[HashArraySize];`

or

```
typedef struct Node  {
    position* p;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
} Node;
```